# Disable screen outputting "[screen is terminating]"

Tags: gnu-screen

How do I disable the output when you are done with a screen from the `screen` command?

Example:

```
function foo()
{
    echo "Testing..."
    sleep 2
    echo "Done!"
}
export -f foo
screen -q bash -c "foo" &> /dev/null
```

It all works as expected, however I cannot find out how to disable the "[screen is terminating]".

Comment: Screen runs detached from your terminal, so you can't use the pipe like you would expect, this won't work for example: `screen -q bash -c "foo" | head -n -1 &> /dev/null`. So the real question is why do you care about this one line of text? If you can answer that, then maybe we can find a solution to *that* problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are only two solutions that I can think of.  The first is to modify the screen code itself and recompile.  The second is to have something like an `expect` wrapper around the program (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn screen -q bash -c foo
interact {
    "\[screen is terminating]" exit
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The screen is using your tty to write that text, so you can't stop the screen to write that text by just redirect stdout or stderr to the `/dev/null`.

I have the simplest way for removing that line from an output.

In this approach you need to move the cursor upward and clear that line.
Escape characters can help you with that, for example,to execute the `screen` command with `cat` command, you need to execute that like:

```
screen cat;echo -en '\e[A\e[K'
```

This will remove the line `[screen is terminating]`.

Comment: Better as `printf '\33[A\33[K'` is many `echo` implementations don't support `-n` or `-e` (Unix compliant ones would need `echo '\33[A\33[K\c'`). Or use `tput cuu1; tput el` to avoid hardcoding the sequences of a specific terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Simple :D

The only way is to modify the "screen" executable.
The best (portable) way to do so is something like this:

```
offset=$(tr -c '[[:print:]]' '\n' <`which screen`|grep -b "screen is terminating" | cut -d ":" -f 1)
printf "\x00" | dd of=`which screen` obs=1 seek=$offset conv=notrunc
```

obviously the script must be re-run every time the package is updated.

Comment: sorry I was in a rush...I'll update it now.